# How to create an event for a specific calendar?

Tags: macos, calendar

I'm using Mountain Lion. My default calendar is "Personal". But I also have a "Work" calendar.

I'd like to be able to create a new event on the Work calendar by doing something like <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + click.

In Calendar, is there a way to create an event for a specific calendar rather than having it first get assigned to the default calendar, then clicking to edit the event and then changing the calendar?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Mountain Lion. Should have specified that. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is actually simpler than that.  In Calendar preferences, click "Default Calendar" and scroll to the bottom and select "Selected Calendar."  Now, whichever calendar you have highlighted in the sidebar becomes the calendar in which you are working.

Comment: Thanks. I tend to view all my calendars at the same time (I'm not that busy!), but this is good to know regardless.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not that easy, but after you create any event, right click on it. Select Calendar and then select the Work Calendar. You can’t just assign shortcuts like that.